# How can I add MUI theme color to inline style?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Lets say I have these tabs below. How can I use the MUI `primary` and `secondary` colors for inline CSS? I would like to use colors from my palette to customize this.

```
            <Tabs
              value={value}
              onChange={handleChange}
              variant='fullWidth'
              aria-label="simple tabs example"
              className="tableViewTabs"
              centered
              color="primary"
              // inkBarStyle={{backgroundColor: '#68C222', width: '33.3%'}}
              // tabItemContainerStyle={{backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF', width: '30%'}} 
          >
                <Tab
                  icon={<GradeIcon/>}
                  {...a11yProps(0)}
                  disableFocusRipple={true}
                  disableRipple = {true}
                  color="primary"
                  style={{ textTransform: "none", fontSize: 16, color: value === 0 ? "" : "" }}
                />
                <Tab
                    icon={<ViewAgendaIcon />}
                    {...a11yProps(1)}
                    disableFocusRipple={true}
                disableRipple={true}
                style={{ textTransform: "none", fontSize: 16, fontWeight: value === 1 ? "bold" : "" }} 
                />
                <Tab
                    icon={<AppsIcon />}
                    {...a11yProps(2)}
                    disableFocusRipple = {true}
                    disableRipple = {true}
                    style={{ textTransform: "none", fontSize: 16, fontWeight: value === 2 ? "bold" : "" }} 
                />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you need to use inline styles, you can get the `theme` object via [`useTheme`](https://material-ui.com/styles/api/#usetheme-theme) hook.

```js
const theme = useTheme()
```

The theme object contains all data about Material-UI theme like color palette, breakpoints, zIndex... You can inspect the `DefaultTheme` object [here](https://mui.com/customization/default-theme).

```js
return <Tabs {...props} style={{ backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.main }} />
```

In **MUI v5**, you can use the [`sx` prop](https://mui.com/system/the-sx-prop/#main-content) to quickly add dynamic styles as an alternative to inline styles. It also has better integration with MUI theme as demonstrated by the [following examples](https://mui.com/system/the-sx-prop/#theme-aware-properties):

```
<Box sx={{ color: 'text.secondary' }}>Text</Box>
<div style={{ color: theme.palette.text.secondary }}>Text</Box>
```

```
<Box sx={{ border: 1 }}>Text</Box>
<div style={{ border: '1px solid black' }}>Text</Box>
```

```
<Box sx={{ borderRadius: 2 }}>Text</Box>
<div style={{ borderRadius: theme.shape.borderRadius * 2 }}>Text</Box>
```

```
<Box sx={{ mx: 2 }}>Text</Box>
<div style={{ margin: `0 ${theme.spacing(2)}` }}>Text</Box>
```

```
<Box sx={{ fontWeight: 'fontWeightLight' }}>Text</Box>
<div style={{ fontWeight: theme.typography.fontWeightLight }}>Text</Box>
```

```
<Box sx={{ zIndex: 'tooltip' }}>Text</Box>
<div style={{ zIndex: theme.zIndex.tooltip }}>Text</Box>
```

```
<Box sx={{ boxShadow: 1 }}>Text</Box>
<div style={{ boxShadow: theme.shadows[1] }}>Text</Box>
```